# Indentation Error from Heroku for this Python bot. I cannot see?

Tags: python

Recently I've deployed a python bot on Heroku and every time I try to run it, this error pops up.

> 2016-12-28 T04:32:08.770156+00:00 app[worker.1]:File "bot.py", line 43
>
> 2016-12-28 T04:32:08.770168+00:00 app[worker.1]: else:
>
> 2016-12-28 T04:32:08.770171+00:00 app[worker.1]:^
>
> 2016-12-28 T04:32:08.770172+00:00 app[worker.1]: IndentationError: expected an indented block

Here's the code block it refers to. What is wrong with the code?

```
class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, raw_data):
        try:
            retweet_ed = raw_data.lower().split('"retweeted":')[1].split(',"possibly_sensitive"')[0].replace(",", "")
            tweet_text = raw_data.lower().split('"text":"')[1].split('","source":"')[0].replace(",", "") #tweet's text
            screen_name = raw_data.lower().split('"screen_name":"')[1].split('","location"')[0].replace(",", "") #tweet's authors screen name
            tweet_sid = raw_data.split('"id":')[1].split('"id_str":')[0].replace(",", "") #tweet's id
    
    
            if not any(a_acc == screen_name.lower() for a_acc in whitelist_acc):
                if not any(acc == screen_name.lower() for acc in banned_accs):
                    if not any(a_wrds in screen_name.lower() for a_wrds in whitelist_words):
                        if not any(word in tweet_text.lower() for word in banned_words):
                            if("false" in retweet_ed):
                                #call what u want to do here
                                #for example :
                                #fav(tweet_sid)
                                #retweet(tweet_sid)
                            else:
                                pass
                                #call what u want to do here
                                #for example :
                                #fav(tweet_sid)
                                #retweet(tweet_sid)
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e)) # prints the error msg, if u dont want it comment it out
            pass
```

Comment: You have commented all the lines of code after your `if` statement. Fix that

Comment: Please read the description for a tag before applying it to your question. The [tag:git] tag is for questions about Git usage and workflows, not programming questions that happen to involve a Git repo. (I've [edited](//stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your question to remove it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you cannot have no code under the `if` statement. That is the most likely culprit and you can fix this by adding `pass` in that block. If you want to test this for yourself, you can run the following very simple example and verify that the interpreter gives an error when you try to run it.

```
if 1 == 1:
else:
    print "This will never print."
```

Second, it is difficult to tell because of re-encoding on SO, but you may also have mixed spaces and tabs incorrectly. If you are using vim, you can do `set list` to show the invisible characters and make sure you are consistent.

Comment: Yes that can be it. but I'm running on free services? any free alternative for this? thanks.

Comment: @AACaN, I do not understand your question. You do not need to pay to change the code as far as I know.

Comment: no i was referring to vim. i have implemented your solution, testing it now.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an `if` statement with no instructions:

```
if("false" in retweet_ed):
    #call what u want to do here
    #for example :
    #fav(tweet_sid)
    #retweet(tweet_sid)
```

Python expects an indent, but since everything is commented out, there is none.

This is basically what the error indicates:

> 2016-12-28 T04:32:08.770168+00:00 app[worker.1]: else:
>
> 2016-12-28 T04:32:08.770171+00:00 app[worker.1]:^
>
> 2016-12-28 T04:32:08.770172+00:00 app[worker.1]: IndentationError:
>   expected an indented block

You cannot have an `else` statement that is not following an indented block (that is, an `if` block, or even a `for`).

---

If you want to keep the `if` in plain code, add a `pass` statement, as for the following `else`:

```
if("false" in retweet_ed):
    #call what u want to do here
    #for example :
    #fav(tweet_sid)
    #retweet(tweet_sid)
    pass
```

Then, the code will not raise any `IndentationError`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include something in the if statement. Just type

```
pass
```

Or set a useless variable for now.

And also, indent everything by one indent I think (because of the first line, correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: You are perfectly right; however, since OP's code ran until that `else` statement, I think it's just a bad copy-paste.

Comment: "Just type print()" isn't a very good way to do a no-op in Python. In fact, `print()` does have an effect. Use [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) instead.

Comment: @Chris Right, although something like `print("Entering if statement")` could help debug.