# Python Syntax Error with Tweepy

Tags: python, heroku, twitter, tweepy

wish you coders all a Happy New year ! 
I had problem with compiling Python on heroku earlier which threw indentation errors and got answered by this thread. 
[Python Bot indentation error, solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355550/indentation-error-from-heroku-for-this-python-bot-i-cannot-see)
Anyhow with the help of you people Im passed the above mentioned error, but a strange syntax error pops up.

```
    banned_accs =  ['@bbc' ,'@cnn']

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='#test').items():

    if not any(acc == tweet.user.screen_name for acc in banned_accs):
       tweet.retweet()
       print('Retweeted the tweet')
       # Favorite the tweet
       tweet.favorite()
       print('Favorited the tweet')
       # Follow the user who tweeted
       tweet.user.follow()
       print('Followed the user')
       sleep(5)       
    else:
       pass

except tweepy.TweepError as e:
print(e.reason)

except StopIteration:
    break
```

Error generated from console is

```
    except tweepy.TweepError as error:
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone help me to figure this out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't seem to have a `try` in your code. This needs to be above the part of code that you expect might throw an exception, and everything should be indented within that block. This is standard in Python and unrelated to `tweepy`.

Comment: where does your try block starts??

Comment: Nonsense mistake made by myself. Sorry I had to put this up here. Thanks for the replies guys. Vote to delete this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `except` blocks but I don't see a `try` block. Perhaps you have not included your entire code in the question.

Most probably you are using a `try` keyword somewhere above in your code or you have forgot to use a `try` block. `except` should have same indentation as that of `try` if there is a `try` block or if you have forgot the `try` block then declare it above the code block which might throw exception.

And `print(e.reason)` should be indented inside the `except` block

Comment: Ofc. What a simple thing to miss. Thanks

Comment: Yes the code don't have a try to catch the except. Bad mistake by myself :/